# How to make animate in continue range in watchkit?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I have an image on WKInterfacecontroller. and i have 10 image frames (frame_0.png to frame_9.png)

in normal when we want to make that image animated we can simple do like this:

```
stopWatchAnimateImage.setImageNamed("frame_")
stopWatchAnimateImage.startAnimating()
```

or we can make animate with Range:

```
stopWatchAnimateImage.setImageNamed("frame_")
stopWatchAnimateImage.startAnimatingWithImagesInRange(NSMakeRange(0, 9) , duration: 10 , repeatCount: 0)
```

but now i want my Image start animated from the frame_3 and continue to make animate after the image run to frame_9

(my image will run from frame 3 -4 -5....to 9 and so on continue to 0 -1 - 2- 3..) 
How can i do that?
I already tried :

```
stopWatchAnimateImage.startAnimatingWithImagesInRange(NSMakeRange(3, 9) , duration: 6 , repeatCount: 0)
```

but not work and this:

```
stopWatchAnimateImage.setImage(UIImage(named: "frame_3"))
stopWatchAnimateImage.startAnimating()
```

but my image become blank.

Comment: Did you try to make the Range (3,9)?

Comment: already tried this: stopWatchAnimateImage.startAnimatingWithImagesInRange(NSMakeRange(3, 9) , duration: 10 , repeatCount: 0) but no luck

Comment: I have just tried it and worked like magic.

Comment: It's only run from frame_3 to frame_9. Could you give your sample code to me to check please? Thanks

Comment: I did write it as an answer to have a bigger space for comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After check some solution, finally we can make this simple like this:
make one animate with range and make delay time , after that we can continue make a continue animated like this:

```
stopWatchAnimateImage.setImageNamed("frame_")
stopWatchAnimateImage.startAnimatingWithImagesInRange(NSMakeRange(3, 9) , duration: 7 , repeatCount: 1)
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(7 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            ), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.stopWatchAnimateImage.startAnimating()

        })
```